# Finding the square root of $6-4\sqrt{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I found [this](https://youtu.be/SOgn6J12NWE) standupmaths video on YouTube about the A4 paper puzzle.

I really liked the puzzle and managed to get the answer by using a calculator. However, the answer (which I won't spoil), led me to think that the equation to solve it might simplify - which it does.

In the middle of the simplification, I got this expression:

$$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}}$$

which for other reasons I suspected to be equal to:

$$\ 2-\sqrt{2}$$

I tried squaring the above and, sure enough, it does give:

$$6-4\sqrt{2}$$

My question is, how would I have been able to find the square root of

$$6-4\sqrt{2}$$

if I hadn't been able to guess at it? Is there a standard technique? I've tried looking on the web but don't really even know what to search for.

Comment: $$2^2+(\sqrt2)^2-2\cdot2\cdot\sqrt2=(2-\sqrt2)^2$$

Answer (score 6):

One way of doing this would be to guess that 
$$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}} = a+b\sqrt2$$
for some $a,b \in \mathbb Z$. Squaring both sides, we get
$$6-4\sqrt2 = a^2+2b^2 + 2ab\sqrt2$$
which implies that $6=a^2+2b^2$ and $-4 = 2ab$. Since $a$ and $b$ are integers, there are two solutions: $(a,b) = (2,-1)$, and $(a,b) = (-2,1)$, and we reject the latter.

Answer (score 4):

We have to assume that the nested radical can be rewritten as the sum of two other radicals (surds).

$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{d}+\sqrt{e}$

Squaring both sides gives us $$6-4\sqrt{2}=d+e+2\sqrt{de}$$

This can be solved by finding $2$ numbers that sum to $6$ and multiply to $4^2\cdot 2/4=8$

($2\sqrt{de}=4\sqrt{2}\rightarrow de=8$)

Numbers $4$ and $2$ work, so $$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{2}=2-\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

The numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ share many arithmetic properties with the integers. That's why you might suspect an answer of that form to the question. So try one:
$$
(a+b\sqrt{2})^2 = a^2 + 2b^2 + 2ab\sqrt{2} = 6-4\sqrt{2}.
$$

Then it's easy to finish.

You can find out more on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer) but you'd have to know to search for "quadratic integer" to find that page.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll spend a little time trying to understand it. Actually, the reason I suspected the answer was because I knew the answer to the puzzle and I was only missing one piece, I didn't know it was going to be of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ just from looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

set $$(a+b\sqrt{2})^2=6-4\sqrt{2}$$ and find the rational numbers $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [@Frank](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/332250/frank)'s answer, there is a general formula for simplifying expressions of the form
$\sqrt{a + \sqrt{b}}$
by assuming the result will take the form $\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}$.

(If the original expression is of the form $\sqrt{a + q\sqrt{b}}$, recall that $q\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{q^2b}$. The formula we will derive will still work.)

$$\sqrt{a + \sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}$$
$$\Rightarrow a + \sqrt{b}=c + d + 2\sqrt{c}\sqrt{d}$$
Assume $a=c+d$ and $b=4cd$
$$\Rightarrow c=a-d$$
$$\Rightarrow b=4(a-d)d$$
$$=4ad-4d^2$$
$$\Rightarrow 4d^2-4ad+b=0$$
Applying quadratic formula,
$$d=\frac{4a\pm\sqrt{16a^2-4*4*b}}{8}$$
$$=\frac{4a\pm\sqrt{16a^2-16b}}{8}$$
$$=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}$$
The two solutions to this equation (presuming they exist) will be $c$ and $d$, respectively. This will only be a simplifying tool if the radicand, $a^2-b$, is a perfect square.

In the case of the OP's question, $a=6$ and $b=32 \Rightarrow a^2-b=36-32=4$, so the formula works. $c$ and $d$ are therefore equal to
$$\frac{6\pm{2}}{2}=2,4$$
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{6 + 4\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{4}$$
$$=2 + \sqrt{2}$$